# confusion about lebesgue measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am currently reading Stein's Real Analysis. The definition of exterior measure is :

> if $E$ is any subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, the exterior measure of $E$ is
> $$
> m_{*}(E)=\inf \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|Q_{j}\right|
> $$
> where the infimum is taken over all countable coverings $E \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} Q_{j}$ by closed cubes.

Then he gives an observation which says

> If $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$, then $m_{*}(E)=\inf m_{*}(\mathcal{O})$, where the infimum is taken over all open sets $\mathcal{O}$ containing $E$.

Given this observation, we can always find an open set $\mathcal{O} \supset E$ s.t. $m_{*}(E) + \epsilon \geq  m_{*}(\mathcal{O})$. My question is, why can't we directly conclude from this that  for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an open set $\mathcal{O}$ with $E \subset \mathcal{O}$ and
$$
m_{*}(\mathcal{O}-E) \leq \epsilon
$$which is the definition for lebesgue measurability?

Comment: Are you sure about this: *we can always find an open set $\mathcal{O} \supset E$ s.t. $m_{*}(E) + \epsilon \geq  m_{*}(\mathcal{O})\;?$*

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a measure $\mu$ must satisfy $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty \mu(A_i) = \mu(\bigcup\limits_{i = 0}^\infty A_i)$ for any pairwise disjoint sequence of measurable sets and $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

In particular, if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, then setting $A_0 = X$, $A_1 = Y$, and $A_n = \emptyset$ for $n \geq 2$ gives us that $\mu(X) + \mu(Y) = \mu(X + Y)$.

If $m_*$ were a measure (on all of $P(\mathbb{R}^n)$), then we would have $m_*(\mathcal{O} - E) + m_*(E) = m_*(\mathcal{O}) \leq m_*(E) + \epsilon$ and therefore $m_*(\mathcal{O} - E) \leq \epsilon$.

But nowhere did we prove that $m_*$ is a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $P(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In fact, the existence of Vitali sets proves that it isn't.

Rather, $m_*$ is merely an outer measure.

Comment: @ Mark Saving. Thank you for your answer. Let's just take the vitali set for example. I think that in the standard proof of its non-measurability, one does not explicitly invoke the definition of lebesgue measurability. So how to understand that the vitali set does not meet the definition of measurability?

Comment: @GGG the proof is by contradiction, so it does begin assuming that the Vitali set is measurable.